# BigQueryML Tensorflow model_path matched no files

Tags: tensorflow, google-bigquery

Having issue creating Tensorflow model in BigQuery. Trained Tensorflow model using Keras, and uploaded the SavedModel directory to GCS. When trying to create model got an error about the model_path:

```
CREATE MODEL `project_name.schema.model_name`
OPTIONS(MODEL_TYPE="TENSORFLOW", MODEL_PATH="gs://tesorflow-model-directory-path/*"
```

Error:

```
Error while reading data, error message: The specified model_path matched no files.
```

Any ideas on how to debug this error, as the model is in GCS, it does work through TF serving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the path points to correct location and check if any documented limitations apply in your case.

Your create model path should include bucket, path and point to the same model_name (directory) that you have used when saving the model, e.g.

```
model.save('model_name')
```

And

```
CREATE MODEL ... MODEL_PATH='gs://your-bucket-name/model_name/*'
```

Is your model larger than 250MB? Are you using TF SavedModelFormat? Are you using supported version and features? Full documented limitations list can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-create-tensorflow#limitations.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, double checked and the model is saved with the same name as I have uploaded the model to GCS, and the model is using supported features and versions (<1MB in size, etc.). Wondering if there is a way to get better error message from BigQuery to be able to debug the issues better?

Comment: Basically this error is saying that gs://tesorflow-model-directory-path/saved_model.pb (or gs://tesorflow-model-directory-path/saved_model.pbtxt) doesn't exist.